# django templates variable issue

Tags: python, django, templates, render

I got a questions, in Django html templates file, I can use the {{ names }} to get a variable from the views.py via render_to_response(). However, how can I do something like this in the HTML templates:

```
{{% for name in names %}}
    ...
{{% endfor %}}
```

I tried to write like

```
{{% for name in {{ names }} %}}
```

of course it doesn't work.

anyone could help me on this? thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the first one?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over list in a template like this:

```
{% for name in names %}
    {{ name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Read more about the [for](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#for) template tag.

Comment: I tried this ,but I got a error, while I saw your code, I know what is my problem, I use {{% %}} instead of {% %}, so I got a error. OMG! I read the docs on djangoproject.com and examples all the afternoon, but I didn't noticed it is because of 2 { }. Thanks very much for the reminding and help.